# Javascript animated clip-path mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css, clip-path

i'm trying to animate clip path with my mouse coordinates. But I can't find a way to do so.
I have two images on top of each others and I'm masking the top one. Any one know if this is possible ?

html :

```
        <div class="scene">
                <div class="magic">1</div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.scene{
    position:relative;
    background-image: url('../img/illustration.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    margin-top:150px;
    margin-left:250px;

}


.magic{
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/illustrationheat.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    clip-path: circle(9.0% at 81% 80%);;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You may find some ideas over there : https://css-tricks.com/animate-a-container-on-mouse-over-using-perspective-and-transform/

Comment: Or this one: https://codepen.io/MihaiIonescu/pen/JpVPLQ